# Some problems with using android Material3 FilterChip

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

> **This is a low-level mistake caused by carelessness, no reference value.  Since someone else answered the question, I had to keep it.**

I created a page with Compose's `FilterChip`:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TestPage() {

    var order by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    val updateIsASCOrder: (b: Boolean) -> Unit = { order = it }

    Row {
        FilterChip(
            border = FilterChipDefaults.filterChipBorder(
                borderColor = Color.Transparent,
                disabledBorderColor = Color.Transparent
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            selected = order,
            onClick = { updateIsASCOrder(true) },
            label = { Text("first") })
        FilterChip(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            selected = !order,
            onClick = { updateIsASCOrder(false) },
            label = { Text("second") })
    }
}
```

Then run the result as follows:
[image]

**How can I remove this gray border?**

There is a concept in `FilterChip` that I don't quite understand,

```kotlin
/**
     * Creates a [SelectableChipBorder] that represents the default border used in a flat
     * [FilterChip].
     *
     * @param borderColor the border color of this chip when enabled and not selected
     * @param selectedBorderColor the border color of this chip when enabled and selected
     * @param disabledBorderColor the border color of this chip when not enabled and not
     * selected
     * @param disabledSelectedBorderColor the border color of this chip when not enabled
     * but selected
     * @param borderWidth the border stroke width of this chip when not selected
     * @param selectedBorderWidth the border stroke width of this chip when selected
     */
    @Composable
    fun filterChipBorder
```

`FilterChip` seems to have two states `enabled` and `selected`. I don't understand what this `enabled` means.

[image]

When I click `second` and select `second`, the border of `first` disappears, which is what I want. But when I check `first`, the border of `second` still won't disappear.

I've tried setting the width of the border to `0dp`, but it still doesn't work, there is still a thin black line.

```kotlin
border = FilterChipDefaults.filterChipBorder(
                borderColor = Color.Transparent,
                disabledBorderColor = Color.Transparent,
                borderWidth = 0.dp,
                selectedBorderWidth = 0.dp
            )
```

Comment: In you first `FilterChip` you are using `borderColor=Color.Transparent` = the border color of this chip when enabled and not selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply in both `FilterChip` the attribute `borderColor = Color.Transparent`.
The border color of this chip is applied when **enabled** and **not selected**.

```
  FilterChip(
        border = FilterChipDefaults.filterChipBorder(
            borderColor = Color.Transparent,
        )
       //....
  )
```

[image].
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I made a stupid mistake. Can you tell me what is enabled? For example, what is the difference between selected and enabled?

Comment: @FreedomFoolt If the chip is disabled you can't select/click it.